# How to trim text fields entered in the node automatically

Tags: 7, entities

Just now i've discovered that my operator was entering many times organization name prefixed/suffixed with a space. For example " Microsoft" or "Microsoft  ".

That is causing problem when this value is being passed as contextual arguments in the views with this space character making a difference.

I need help as to how I can trim already fed in text and secondly store only trimmed version of text.

I could only find [this](http://www.exratione.com/2012/06/drupal-trim-all-form-fields-everywhere/) useful page about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

To correct all those values entered into the database already, I'd suggest doing a mysql trim on those values and resetting them. Make sure you backup the tables first of course, but something like this should do it (if your field name is field_text_test):

```
UPDATE field_data_field_text_test SET field_text_test_value = TRIM(field_text_test_value);
UPDATE field_revision_field_text_test SET field_text_test_value = TRIM(field_text_test_value);
```

After you've run those statements, do a flush all caches on your drupal site.

And then to avoid this happening again, you could use the [Form API Validation](https://drupal.org/project/fapi_validation) module which adds a trim filter on fields.